# How to implement a createMaterialTopTabNavigator with a createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I'm trying to make a `createBottomTabNavigator` with a  `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` on one of the tabs. It's not recognizing the createMaterialTopTabNavigator, and it's telling me `the component for route 'Home' must be a react component`. I do have to component imported correctly. Any ideas?

```
export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(

{
    Home: AppTabs,

    'News': {
        screen: News,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'News',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="newspaper-o" type="font-awesome" size={26} color={tintColor} />,
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: '#2896d3',
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    'Garage': {
        screen: Garage,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Garage',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="garage" type="material-community" size={34} color={tintColor} />,
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: '#2896d3',
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    'Chatbot': {
        screen: Chatbot,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Support',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="ios-person-outline" type="ionicon" size={34} color={tintColor} />,
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: '#2896d3',
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'News',
}
);

const AppTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Tab1: NewApps,
    Tab2: OtherApps,
}, {
        tabBarOptions: {
            scrollEnabled: true,
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 12,
            },
            tabStyle: {
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
            },
            style: {
                backgroundColor: 'tomato',
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
            }
        },
    });

export const createRootNavigator = () => {
    return createStackNavigator(
        {
            Home: {
                screen: Login,
                navigationOptions: {
                    header: null,
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                }
            },
            Tabs: {
                screen: Tabs,
                navigationOptions: {
                    header: null,
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                }
            },
            ViewApp: {
                screen: ViewApp,
                navigationOptions: {
                    header: null,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            headerMode: "none",
            mode: "modal"
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the pathname "home" inside createRootNavigator and also inside createBottomTabNavigator, remember that the names of the routes can not be repeated within the Stacks.

Sorry for my English.